# Angular 2 variable unreachable

Tags: angular, variables

I'm working on a switch button which gets animated and has its appearance changed by the current Viewmode (Card or List).

I have this code in my TS file:

```js
export enum ViewMode {
    List,
    Card
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-viewchanger',
    templateUrl: './viewchanger.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./viewchanger.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('ActiveViewMode', [
            state('inactive', style({
                color: 'mat-color($mat-grey, 50)',
                background: 'transparent'
            })),
            state('active', style({
                color: 'mat-color($mat-grey, 900)',
                background: 'mat-color($mat-grey, 50)'
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('500ms ease')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('500ms ease'))
        ])
    ]
})
export class ViewchangerComponent implements OnInit {
    state = 'inactive';
    viewModes = ViewMode;
    @Input() viewMode = ViewMode.List;
    @Output() ViewModeChange = new EventEmitter<ViewMode>();
    @ContentChild(CardviewDirective) cardTemplate: CardviewDirective;
    @ContentChild(ListviewDirective) listTemplate: ListviewDirective;

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    changeViewMode(viewMode: ViewMode) {
        this.viewMode = viewMode;
        this.ViewModeChange.next(viewMode);
    }

    get activeTemplate() {
        if (this.viewMode === ViewMode.Card) {
            return this.cardTemplate ? this.cardTemplate.templateRef : undefined;
             this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
        }
        return this.listTemplate ? this.listTemplate.templateRef : undefined;
         this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
    }

}
```

And this one in my HTML:

```html
<div class="viewchange-container">
    <i class="fa fa-th" (click)="changeViewMode(viewModes.Card)" [@ActiveViewMode]='state'></i>
    <i class="fa fa-list" (click)="changeViewMode(viewModes.List)" [@ActiveViewMode]='state'></i>
</div>

<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="activeTemplate"></ng-template>
```

My problem is the get activeTemplate() function can't reach the state variable (if I use it in an another function without return it does. I'd like to achieve switching view and the state at the same time.

Comment: Any code after a `return` won't be called - this happens at the end of `activeTemplate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any code after a `return` won't be called - this happens at the end of `activeTemplate`

Change the order to be:

```js
get activeTemplate() {
    if (this.viewMode === ViewMode.Card) {
         this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
        return this.cardTemplate ? this.cardTemplate.templateRef : undefined;
    }
    this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
    return this.listTemplate ? this.listTemplate.templateRef : undefined;
}
```